# Помогите разобраться с urlpatterns в Django2.2 при переходе с 1.9

Tags: django

Вопрос: Как с помощью path или re_path изменить urlpatterns?

**Файл views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product


# Create your views here.

# Страница с товарами
def ProductList(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    })
# Страница товара
def ProductDetail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', {'product': product})
```

**Файл urls.py приложения**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProductList, name='ProductListByCategory'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProductDetail, name='ProductDetail'),
    url(r'^$', views.ProductList, name='ProductList'),
]
```

**Файл urls.py основной**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop'))
]
```

Comment: Вы вопрос забыли написать.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, уже исправил. Вопрос указал в начале

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Что значит изменить? Какие трудности возникли при использовании path?

Comment: Если я url() заменю на re_path() это будет верно? или надо как-то иначе?

Comment: Если получится в соответствии с [документацией](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions), значит верно

Answer (score 0):

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shop.urls')),
]
```

**shop/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from shop import views

app_name = 'shop'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='lst_by_ctgry'),
    # id необязателен, можно передать просто slug товара
    path('<slug:slug>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

Comment: «id необязателен, можно передать просто slug товара» — и всё сломается, потому что вьюха ожидает в аргументах именно id